# Printing in assembly with drawing

Tags: assembly, printing, x86, dos, tasm

I am creating a sign up page and a login page in assembly tasm ms-dos. I am trying to print "Name:" on the screen, but it doesn't work as long as there is a drawing on the screen. Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
proc SignUpPage
    mov ah, 0   ; set display mode function.
    mov al, 13h ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
    int 10h     ; set it!
    mov al, 0Fh
    mov cx, -1  ;col
    mov dx, -1 ;row
    mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel
    ;jmp WRITE
    signUpTopBar:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 640
    jne signUpTopBar

    mov cx, 10  ; reset to start of col
    inc dx      ;next row
    cmp dx, 30
    jne signUpTopBar

    mov al, 0h
    mov cx, 0  ;col
    mov dx, 5  ;row
    mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel


    loginButton:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 60
    jne loginButton

    mov cx, 0  ; reset to start of col
    inc dx      ;next row
    cmp dx, 30
    jne loginButton

    call printNewLine
    call printNewLine
    mov dx, offset LoginMessage
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 0h
    int 33h
    mov ax, 1h
    int 33h
    pressLogin:
    mov ax, 3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne pressLogin
    shr cx, 1
    sub dx, 2
    cmp cx, 60
    ja pressLogin
    cmp dx, 5
    jb pressLogin
    cmp dx, 30
    ja pressLogin
    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 200
    BREAKLINE_SIGNUP:
        call printNewLine
        inc si
        loop BREAKLINE_SIGNUP
    call LoginPage
    WRITE:
    MOV  DL, 0   ;SCREEN COLUMN.
    MOV  DH, 7     ;SCREEN ROW.
    MOV  AH, 2     ;SERVICE TO SET CURSOR POSITION.
    MOV  BH, 0     ;PAGE NUMBER.
    INT  10H       ;BIOS SCREEN SERVICES.
    mov dx, offset nameMessage
    mov ah, 09h 
    int 21h
    
    
    ret
endp SignUpPage

proc LoginPage
    mov ah, 0   ; set display mode function.
    mov al, 13h ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
    int 10h     ; set it!
    mov al, 0Fh
    mov cx, -1  ;col
    mov dx, -1 ;row
    mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel

   
    loginTopBar:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 640
    jne loginTopBar

    mov cx, 10  ; reset to start of col
    inc dx      ;next row
    cmp dx, 30
    jne loginTopBar

    mov al, 0h
    mov cx, 0  ;col
    mov dx, 5  ;row
    mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel


    signUpButton:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 70
    jne signUpButton

    mov cx, 0  ; reset to start of col
    inc dx      ;next row
    cmp dx, 30
    jne signUpButton

    call printNewLine
    call printNewLine
    mov dx, offset SignUpMessage
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 0h
    int 33h
    mov ax, 1h
    int 33h
    pressSignUp:
    mov ax, 3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne pressSignUp
    shr cx, 1
    sub dx, 2
    cmp cx, 60
    ja pressSignUp
    cmp dx, 5
    jb pressSignUp
    cmp dx, 30
    ja pressSignUp
    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 200
    call SignUpPage
    ret
endp LoginPage
```

call printNewLine is a function to print a new line from an assembly library

Answer (score 0):

### The *WRITE* is never executed!

Right before you attempt this *WRITE*, you `call` the *LoginPage* but that nevers returns because it ends with `call`ing the *SignUpPage* which effectively creates an endless loop!!!

### You got lots of undefined behaviour!

The screen that you use has 320 pixels horizontally and 200 pixels vertically. Nonetheless your code is requesting BIOS to plot pixels in the X-range [0,**640**] and the Y-range [**-1**,29].